# Convert a column B into a comma separated list , "ORDER BY" Colum A

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

trying start with VB in excel
just need understand how it works , this task can be done in SQL,
but I really want to know how can be easy done in excel 
column A contains par numbers , column b models 
need in column A unique  part number record , and in column b , coma separated list of models this part can be fitted in.

```
Column A     Column B
B00002455    C50EKB
B00002455    C50EKS
B00002455    C50EKW
B00002456    C50EKX
B00002456    C50ELB
```

Looking for result -

```
ColumA        ColumnB 
B00002455     C50EKB, C50EKS, C50EKW 
B00002456     C50EKX,C50ELB
```

Comment: Try using a `scripting.dictionary` to create an array that will do what you want

Comment: Welcome to Super User. You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, which will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, if they are in order. If they aren't, then filter column A.

```
Sub test()
Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim i As Integer

For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i - 1, 1) Then
        Cells(i - 1, 2) = Cells(i - 1, 2) & ", " & Cells(i, 2)
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

If they aren't in order and you don't want to filter, you're going to need a dictionary, I think.